# CSS button rendering issue on Internet Explorer using CSS filter gradient

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, filter

For some reason, only the top half of a button appears in Internet Explorer. The button renders fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

We are using "filter:progid:DXImageTransform" to apply a CSS gradient to the button with CSS.

Here's the site: http://www.tekiki.com.  (There is only one button on the page right now.)

Any clues?

Comment: The way IE's proprietary CSS filters worked changed significantly in IE8.  Which version(s) of IE are you finding the issue with the button being cut off?

Comment: PS it looks fine in IE9 (***IF*** IE9 is running in Standards mode (currently it runs in IE7 mode))  Can you remove this tag? or do you need it? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1) I'd recommend trying out [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/), it allows you to use gradients etc and will have sorted out many issues that you might face.

2) IE9 doesn't have the filter support, so if you want it to work there you will need to use either an image, or a datauri of an SVG image like this:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdefs%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3ClinearGradient%20id%3D%22grad%22%20x1%3D%220%22%20y1%3D%2250%25%22%20x2%3D%220%22%20y2%3D%22100%25%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstop%20offset%3D%220%22%20stop-color%3D%22%23ff0000%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstop%20offset%3D%221%22%20stop-color%3D%22%23000000%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FlinearGradient%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdefs%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20style%3D%22fill%3Aurl%28%23grad%29%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A");
```

That's made by urlencoding an svg that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <defs>
         <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="50%" x2="0" y2="100%">
             <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff0000" />
             <stop offset="1" stop-color="#000000" />
         </linearGradient>
     </defs>
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#grad)" />
</svg>
```

That has the advantage of working in Opera as well.

This means you'd do the normal grad, then that, then the filter to cover modern browsers, IE9, Opera and IE8 and down.

At this point, you may decide to write a script that generates an image of a grad for you, like this one: http://www.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/2010/dynamically-drawing-gradients-with-php/

Comment: Thanks, Rich. Why did MSFT scale back filter support? It seems like requiring images or datauris of an SVG image makes applying filters harder? There's no pure CSS way to apply filters in IE9 at all?

Comment: All filters are removed in IE9 because they aren't part of any standard. To be fair, the gradient stuff isn't finalised either, so I do understand why they didn't include it. I've updated my answer with the SVG idea.